# EXTJS 5: Why does Ext.grid.Panel have no stripRows effect, after I change the Theme from Neptune to crisp

Tags: extjs, grid, gridpanel

I use sencha -sdk ./ext-5.0.1 generate MyApp ./MyApp to get a new Application.
And run sencha app watch, 
Develop Tool Netbeans 8.02, Google Chrome with Netbeans connector.
Then I create a Gridpanel with 4 data lines, and add it in Main.js

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.grid.GroupsList', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.GridPanel',
    ....
```

Even I don't set the stripRows to true, I still get a  stripRows effect.
I want change the theme by change the app.json file

```
"theme": "ext-theme-neptune", to "theme": "ext-theme-crisp",
```

The google chrome automatic refresh 2 or 3 times, then the theme changed, but no more stripRows.
I add "stripRows:true" or "viewConfig: {stripRows: true}" in the defination of Gridpanel, no effect.
When I change the app.json file back to 'neptune', stripRows is back.
I tested more themes:
"aria" everything is OK.
"classic" everything is OK.

But if I set "stripRows: false" or "viewConfig: {stripRows: false}" , the stripRows is always there.

Answer (score 4):

The correct property is

```
viewConfig: {
    stripeRows: true
},
```

strip**e**Rows not stripRows.

Neptune theme has striped rows turned on by default, crips doesn't.
That's why you get them in neptune although using wrong property.